# What is the best way to install Node and npm on a Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, installation

I've got a new Mac. I would like to install Node and npm on it. I'd like to have control over the Node and npm versions that I install and uninstall on my system. What is the most appropriate way to achieve that?

Comment: Many people (including myself) are interested in the idiomatic way to install a js stack (node, npm). It would be more useful for the community to provide a link to such a question (clearly what OP wanted to know) instead of closing the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). You can install it using

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.7/install.sh | bash`

then run

`nvm install node`